# After injecting html by jquery, the event handlers doesn't work with/without delegate

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a list of `<div>` s with same html but different values inside html. The hierarchy is the following ;

```
<div id="element">
    <div class="likecomm">
        <a class="commenticon" href="#">...some value according to the returning value...</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="element">
    <div class="likecomm">
        <a class="commenticon" href="#">...some value according to the returning value...</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In an event, I inject html to the top of the list which is another `<div id="element> ... </div>`

I have the following event handler for comment icon click;

```
$('.commenticon').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.actionframe').next('nav').slideToggle(300);
    return false;
});
```

It works correct until I insert the new `<div id="element> ... </div>`. The comment icon click event handler doesn't match. I searched about that problem, all were saying that `.delegate()` should be used.

My problem is I don't know where to use the delegate function. Before, I get the results from ajax in order to inject the `<div id="element> ... </div>` , I used `.delegate()` function in ajax call that injects html.

```
$.ajax({

    success:function(data) {

        var html=... // the necessary div html binded with data
        // prepend function call()

        $('.likecomm').delegate(".commenticon","click" , function() {                      
                       $(this).closest('.actionframe').next('nav').slideToggle(300);
                       return false;
        }); 

    }        
});
```

Currently, it doesn't work. So, any ideas how to make this thing work ?

Comment: Why do you have two elements with the same `id`. When you are holding `id`s in `siblings` it is best to maintain their uniqueness.

Comment: If you are using jquery 1.7+ consider using on() instead of click() or delegate(). it should do the job.

Comment: [Live function](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [on function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with this trick: `$(document).on("click", selectorString, f);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to bind the event handler to a common ancestor of the elements on which it should be triggered. For example, if your `#element` gets appended inside a `div` with an `id` of `parent`:

```
$("#parent").delegate(".commenticon", "click", function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

This would be for an HTML structure like so:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="element">

    </div>
    <div class="element">

    </div>
</div>
```

The reason this works is that DOM events bubble up the tree from the point at which they originate. The `delegate` method captures the event at an ancestor element and checks whether or not it originated at an element matching the selector.

Also note that it's invalid to have duplicate `id` values in the same document. Here I've changed your `element` ID values to class names instead.

Finally, if you are using jQuery 1.7+ you should use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead. It will have the same effect, but notice the reversal of the first 2 arguments:

```
$("#parent").on("click", ".commenticon", function() {
    //Do stuff
};
```

Comment: a note, "delegate" is superseeded by "on" as of jquery 1.7.

Comment: @Asken - Yes, I'm getting to that.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `<div id="element> ... </div>` which means that those doesn't exist initially. You need to add delegate to upper level that exists. Then any `.commenticon` that is added under the "container" will have click event.

```
$('#container').delegate(".commenticon","click" , function() {                      
    $(this).closest('.actionframe').next('nav').slideToggle(300);
    return false;
});
```