# click doesn't fire in jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with my Ajax call. In success function, I want to trigger a click on a element but it doesn't fire.

Here is the code :

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/test/'+clubID,
    beforeSend:function(){
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    },
    complete:function(){
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    },
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        if(!jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)) {
            $('#camera-input').click();
            console.log($('#camera-input'));
            console.log('click');
        } else {
            toast('Il est possible de prendre des photos uniquement lors d\'une soirée');
            console.log('toast');
        }
    }
});
```

The console print click and the element. Any ideas about the problem ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger a click"? This triggers click handlers, but it doesn't prompt the native click behaviour.

Comment: Do you have code that bound to the click event you are executing? Make sure your bind is actually setup.

Comment: Does $('#camera-input') return the expected element? When calling it in the debugger you can also see there if the click handler that you want to call is actually bound.

Comment: if I put $('#camera-input').click(); before the ajax call, it opens the windows to choose a file. I want to reproduce that, but in the success function

Comment: Yes, it returns true and there is no error in the console. Maybe there is a problem with jQuery Mobile and Ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try... this is my research, not my experience. No guarantees.

You may need to bind the event handler to a common ancestor of the elements on which it should be triggered. For example, if your #element gets appended inside a div with an id of parent:

```
$("#parent").on("click", ".commenticon", function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

This would be for an HTML structure like so:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="element">

    </div>
    <div class="element">

    </div>
</div>
```

DOM events bubble up the tree from the point at which they originate. The on() (formerly delegate - jQuery pre 1.7) method captures the event at an ancestor element and checks whether or not it originated at an element matching the selector.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391069/after-injecting-html-by-jquery-the-event-handlers-doesnt-work-with-without-del)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

$('#camera-input').trigger('click');